# Array list from the user

Tags: python-2.7

i'm newbie here. And, i still python beginner.
I'm really stuck for answer one "Quiz" at my study place.
Maybe has been 2 weeks, I still failed answer this quiz.
Here we go..

"Make a script loop and produce array list from the user...
Like this.

$ python blablabla.py

> input: 3
>
> > [1, 2, 3]
>
> input: 2
>
> > [2, 4, 3]
>
> input: 6
>
> > [3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
>
> input: 1
>
> > [4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
>
> input:1
>
> > [5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]

Can explain that? that list not created by myself. Must produce by the user.
Thanks before master.
Note: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work?

```
#! /usr/bin/python 

list = []
while True:
    num = raw_input('please enter your number: ')
    print("You've entered", num)

    if len(list) < int(num):
        for i in range(0, len(list)):
            list[i]=list[i]+(i+1)
        for i in range(len(list), int(num)):
                list.append(i+1)
    else:
        for i in range(0, int(num)):
            list[i]=list[i]+(i+1)

    print list
```

Comment: Thanks master, this work! So, for make a array list from the user. We must use raw_input? and can we make a list from this num=[input('Please enter your number: ')} ?

Comment: I had some error with using "input" to capture the number.  raw_input worked without error.

Comment: I see, same like me. Ok Thanks for the help master :)

Comment: Mister yftse is fine.